# Update bundler version using capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, capistrano, rvm1-capistrano3

I've multiple servers and they are running the bundler version `2.1.4` and I want to upgrade the bundler to `2.3.5`, so I tried to write the `capistrano` task

```
namespace :update_bundler do
  desc "Install the bundler 2.3.5"
  task :install do
    on roles(:all) do
      execute "gem install bundler -v 2.3.5"
    end
  end
end
```

In deploy config I have added the following line

```
before "bundler:install", "update_bundler:install"
```

But it throw the following error

```
      01 bash: gem: command not found
#<Thread:0x000000014d2e5ce0 /Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    9: from /Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    8: from /Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
    7: from /Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
    6: from /Users/umairkhalid/Documents/workingProjects/test-project/lib/capistrano/tasks/update_bundler.rake:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    5: from /Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
    4: from /Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
    3: from /Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
    2: from /Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
    1: from /Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `execute_command'
/Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status=': gem install bundler -v 2.3.5 exit status: 127 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
gem install bundler -v 2.3.5 stdout: Nothing written
gem install bundler -v 2.3.5 stderr: bash: gem: command not found
    1: from /Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/umairkhalid/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/sshkit-1.21.2/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as [SERVER_USERNAME]@[SERVER_IP_ADDRESS]: gem install bundler -v 2.3.5 exit status: 127 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
gem install bundler -v 2.3.5 stdout: Nothing written
gem install bundler -v 2.3.5 stderr: bash: gem: command not found
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as [SERVER_USERNAME]@[SERVER_IP_ADDRESS]: gem install bundler -v 2.3.5 exit status: 127
gem install bundler -v 2.3.5 stdout: Nothing written
gem install bundler -v 2.3.5 stderr: bash: gem: command not found
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'capistrano', require: false 
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-sidekiq'
  #gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  #gem 'rvm-capistrano'
  gem 'rvm1-capistrano3', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-npm'
  gem 'capistrano-ssh-doctor', git: 'https://github.com/capistrano-plugins/capistrano-ssh-doctor.git'
```

I'm using the rails 6.1.4

Updated:
deploy.rb

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.16"

set :application, test-project
set :repo_url, test-project-git-link
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true }

# Default branch is :master
# ask :branch, `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
 set :deploy_to, "/home/test-project"
 set :keep_releases, 2

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
# set :format, :airbrussh

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# append :linked_files, "config/database.yml"
append :linked_files, "config/application.yml"

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system"
append :linked_dirs, ".bundle"
#append :linked_dirs, "node_modules"

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
# set :keep_releases, 5

# RVM configuration (see https://github.com/rvm/rvm-capistrano)
# use the same ruby as used locally for deployment
set :rvm1_ruby_string, :local
set :rvm1_ruby_version, '2.7.2' 
# make bundler use the RVM gemset instead of a local directory
set :bundle_path, nil
set :bundle_flags, '--system'

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure

# Setup for capistrano-sidekiq
set :sidekiq_roles, [:worker]
set :init_system, :systemd


before "update_bundler:install", 'rvm1:hook'
before "bundler:install", "update_bundler:install"
after "deploy:finished", "figaro_config:upload"
after "deploy:finished", "stealth_evasions:build"
#after "deploy:finished", "sidekiq:restart"


#require "rvm/capistrano"

# set :rvm_ruby_string, :local        # use the same ruby as used locally for deployment

# before 'deploy', 'rvm:install_rvm'  # install/update RVM
# before 'deploy', 'rvm:install_ruby' # install Ruby and create gemset (both if missing)
```

Comment: Are you using `rvm` locally, or also on the servers? It seems like your Ruby is not found, possibly because the correct rvm ruby has not been selected (yet)?

Comment: Yes I'm using `rvm` on both local and servers

Comment: Ah, my guess would then be that you're missing the 'rvm setup' task / command that makes sure the correct rvm env is selected. Can you check how that is done for one of your Capistrano tasks that works?

Comment: It's the first task which is related to ruby? Can you provide me some reference guide I've been trying to fix it from last night.

Comment: Can you share your full `config/deploy.rb`? That might give some start point to debug.

Comment: Shared the complete `deploy.rb` file